# Use placeholder to get value from models in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, model, placeholder

I would to use placeholder system to get values from database.

Suppose I have this string:

```
PB/[[document.protocol_number]]/[[user.code]]
```

I need to replace placeholders inside [[ and ]] with correspondence on models.

For example:

```
[[document.protocol_number]]
```

have to get "protocol_number" column from model "document".

Do you know already exits something to do this job? Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I adopted this way:
I created a function to decode my placeholders like this:

```
function placeholder_decode($placeholder, $document)
{
    $variables['#user.code#'] = Auth::user()->code;
    $variables['#document.protocol_number#'] = str_pad($document->protocol_number, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $variables['#document.address.name#'] = $document->address->name;
    $variables['#document.subject#'] = $document->subject;
    $variables['#document.date#'] = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $document->protocol_date)->format("d/m/Y");
    $variables['#document.protocol_number_view#'] = $document->protocol_number_view;
    $variables['#company.name#'] = Auth::user()->company->name;

    $string = json_decode(str_replace(array_keys($variables), array_values($variables), $placeholder));

    return $string[0]->value;

}
```

I don't like the return way, any other suggestions?

An other problem is that the line

```
$variables['#document.protocol_number_view#'] = $document->protocol_number_view;
```

call an accessor into `document` model. This return me an error...